# UAG not redirecting SilverLight Org Chart Pic Links

Tags: my-site, silverlight, ssl, forefront

We have a ForeFront UAG server publishing two SP 2010 web apps externally. The first is the portal site, and the second is My Sites. UAG is terminating SSL and is also redirecting any port 80 requests, but ONLY for external connections (using split-DNS).

A problem we are having is that the Org Chart in My Sites appears to be using absolute URLs when it tries to load the thumbnail pictures for the org chart. When users come in through the UAG gateway, the thumbnail pictures load on MySites, but only when the browser is retrieving them with GET since UAG is doing the proxying for SSL to non-SSL. This causes the Org Chart to display the default thumbnail picture instead of the actual ones. We have confirmed that this only happens through UAG.

Is there a way to use relative URLs for the pictures, as this would satisfy the need for non-SSL inside, and SSL outside?

Comment: Can you please specify the SharePoint patch level (SP, CU, Build Version)? There are some known bugs fixed in some releases like: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2475878 (Bullet 6)

Comment: The farm is running SPS enterprise at SP1, 14.0.6029.1000. If it helps to clarify, we loaded pictures in with a script, [link](http://sharepoint.licomputersource.com/2010/12/uploading-user-profile-pictures-programmatically/), similar to this instead of using AD.

Comment: As an update, I did open a ticket with Microsoft and they had us apply the above hotfix and apply the June 2011 CU. This did not resolve the issue.

Comment: We are using ISA 2006 server /w SharePoint 2010 with a main portal web app and a My Site web app, and we are experiencing the exact same issues. ISA -> WFE is all SSL, no HTTP involved, but still the same issue. If we hit the WFE directly without going through ISA, it works as expected and pictures show up. Did you ever figure out the answer to this problem?

Comment: Yes, you have to do some trickery with the AAMs. I did a blog writeup on it here: http://blog.lapill.us/2012/05/sharepoint-and-reverse-proxies.html